# Update query over nested select query

Tags: mysql-5.1

Want to update status of only those record whose a_msisdn count > 100 on specific date:

```
mysql> select * from cc_info limit 1;
+----------------------+--------------+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+
| transaction_id       | a_msisdn     | a_imsi | a_sub_type | a_lang_code | b_msisdn     | b_imsi | b_sub_type | b_lang_code | incoming_timestamp  | process_timestamp   | request_mode | status | retry_counter |
+----------------------+--------------+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+
| -9223371087585181184 | 923345070688 |        |          0 |           0 | 923333340955 |        |          1 |           0 | 2019-08-04 15:58:42 | 2019-08-04 15:58:49 |            0 |      3 |             0 |
```

---

**UPDATE** (moved from comments)

```
update cc_info 
set status =4 
where a_msisdn = ( select a_msisdn 
                   from cc_info 
                   where DATE(incoming_timestamp) ='2019-08-04' 
                     AND status = 3 
                   group by a_msisdn 
                   having count(*) > 100 );
```

But I am getting the error

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: The query i have tried:

Comment: update cc_info 
    set status =4 
where a_msisdn = (
                    select a_msisdn 
                    from cc_info 
                    where DATE(incoming_timestamp) ='2019-08-04' 
                    AND status = 3 
                    group by a_msisdn 
                    having count(*) > 100
                );

Comment: But I am getting the error

ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update cc_info dst, ( select a_msisdn 
                      from cc_info 
                      where DATE(incoming_timestamp) ='2019-08-04' 
                        AND status = 3 
                      group by a_msisdn 
                      having count(*) > 100 ) src
set dst.status = 4 
where dst.a_msisdn = src.a_msisdn
```

Comment: ! How can we optimize the above query if record in table cc_info almost 4 million????

Comment: `CREATE INDEX idx_name ON cc_info (status, incoming_timestamp, a_msisdn)` (or the same, but with the first two fields swapped) may help.

Comment: Starting from 8.0.13 you may create more effective index: `CREATE INDEX idx_name ON cc_info (status, (DATE(incoming_timestamp)), a_msisdn)`, but your version cannot...